# Matching ranges with a checkbox

Tags: vba, checkbox

I think this is simple but I'm new to VBA. I have a row that I would like to be either 0 or a value from a different row (matching length and position). I have a computed financial statement line that I would like to bring into a different financial statement or null depending on a checkbox. Here is what I have so far but it just returns E111 for the entire range, I would like E60=E111, F60=F111, etc.

```
Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    `With Worksheets("Project Model").Range("E60:KX60")
        `If CheckBox2.Value = True Then .Value = 0
        `If CheckBox2.Value = False Then .Value = ("E111)
    End With
End Sub
```

Anyone know a quick fix?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
With Worksheets("Project Model").Range("E60:KX60")
    If (CheckBox2.Value = True) Then
        .Value = 0
    Else
        .Value = Worksheets("Project Model").Range("E111:KX111").Value
    End If
End With
```

Also, note that if your CheckBox is located within the 'Project Model' sheet itself, then you do not need to explicitly specify the worksheet by name in your code (which will result in an error if you later change the worksheet name without updating the code too).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for. The CheckBox is on the same page as your data.

CheckBox - **Checked:** 
Display "0" for ranges E60:KX60.

CheckBox - **Unchecked:** 
For ranges E60:KX60 display the column's letter followed by "111".
Ex. "E111"

```
Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim col As String

    If CheckBox2.Value = True Then Range("E60:KX60").Value = 0

    If CheckBox2.Value = False Then
        'For Ranges E to KX
        For i = 5 To 310
            'Get Column Address
            col = Cells(60, i).address(False, False)
            'Remove "60" from Column Address
            col = Left(col, Len(col) - 2)
            'Display column and "111"
            Cells(60, i).Value = col & "111"
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```